# Render MVC label with asterisk dynamically based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, required

I am working in MVc project. I have to show the asterisk (*) symbol for required field, but my field is not required always, it may required some cases and it may not required some cases.

my employee view model would be

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [RequiredExtendAttribute("Manager", 121)]
        [RequiredExtendAttribute("Developer", 4)]
        public string FeedBack { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I have added `RequiredExtendAttribute` for Feedback property, which means, the feedback field will be mandatory when the logged in user is manager and his experience is 121, also for Developer and his experience is 4.

I am validating those fields like below,

```
 public class RequiredExtendAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IMetadataAware
    {
        string _role;
        int _experience;

        public RequiredExtendAttribute(string role, int experience)
        {
            _role = role;
            _experience = experience;
        }

        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues["Role"] = _role;
            metadata.AdditionalValues["Experience"] = _experience;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if(_role == "Manager" && _experience > 120 && value == null ) // _experience in months
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if(_role == "Developer" && _experience < 6 && value == null )
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here I used `IMetadataAware` interface to store the role and experience value in property meta data, so that I can read the same value to render the label with * symbol.

I have created the html helper class like below.

```
public static IHtmlString RequiredLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

            string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            string labelText = metaData.DisplayName ?? metaData.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();

            string _role = string.Empty;
            int _experience = 0;

            if (metaData.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Role"))
            {
                _role = metaData.AdditionalValues["Role"] as string;
            }
            if (metaData.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Experience"))
            {
                _experience = Convert.ToInt32(metaData.AdditionalValues["Experience"]);
            }

            if ((_role == "Manager" && _experience > 120) || (_role == "Developer" && _experience < 6))
            {
                labelText += "<span class=\"red\">*</span>";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.Attributes.Add("for", helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));

            label.InnerHtml = labelText;
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
        }
```

I logged-in as developer with experience as 3. My problem is  `metaData.AdditionalValues["Role"]` this line returns always Manager not Developer. How to do this, Appreciate for your helps.

Thanks

Comment: Custom attributes and data annotations are not always the best solution. In your case, having two different view models for Managers and Developers or having two different Feedback fields would make your code a lot simpler and easier to read.

Comment: I agree with Mr. ataravati.  This could be handled much better with a property in a ViewModel.

Comment: You can only apply one attribute of the same type to a property. And `metaData.AdditionalValues` is a dictionary - you cannot add multiple values with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add more properties to your model, and one to check if it should be required

```
public bool IsRequired
{
    get
    {
        Role.Equals("Manager") && Experience == 121 ||
        Role.Equals("Developer") && Experience == 4
    }
}
```

Then use `RequiredIf`

```
[RequiredIf("IsRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "Feedback is Required!")]
public string FeedBack { get; set; }
```

Your model should look like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("IsRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "Feedback is Required!")]
    public string FeedBack { get; set; }

    public string Role {get; set;}

    public int Experience {get; set;}

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get
        {
            Role.Equals("Manager") && Experience == 121 ||
            Role.Equals("Developer") && Experience == 4
        }
    }
}
```

Please note:

`Required if` is not a built-in attribute. You need to download and import third party library:

[**MVC Foolproof Validation**](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

As for the asterisk sign, in your custom helper class,

You would just check for `IsRequired` property:

```
bool required = metadata.IsRequired;
if(required) 
    labelText += "<span class=\"red\">*</span>";
```

Comment: Hi Meda, Thanks for your reply. I agree what you are suggesting, but if we  have more properties like Feedback with different condition, how can I do that,

Comment: sorry for the delay, please put all condition needed to make the feedback required inside of `public bool IsRequired`